# "brush up" and "go over"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are there differences between "brush up" and "go over" say in the following example:

> go over all information

and

> brush up all information

Comment: Not your question, but I would use "review all the information".

Comment: The second idiom should be _brush up on_, I think, not just _brush up_. I would say, "I'm going back to school next month; I need to brush up ***on*** my calculus," not, "...brush up my calculus."

Comment: [brush something up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brush+up)
to improve one's knowledge of something or one's ability to do something. (See also brush up (on something).) _I need to brush my French up a little bit. I need to brush up my French._

Answer (score 2):

To me, to *go over* some information is to read it in a flash, that is, not too deeply. Whereas to *brush up* on some information to *re-read* something I've already read before, to remind myself of the contents.

Comment: I completely agree with your definition of *brush up* as "re-learn or re-read something", but I'd say *go over* doesn't imply speed. A teacher might say, "Today in class, we'll go over a new way to perform integrals." -- it doesn't necessarily mean the topic will be covered quickly; it only means that the topic will be discussed. If I wanted to imply speed, I would use "quickly go over", e.g., "We'll quickly go over the notes from last week."

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, I agree. Perhaps I misread and saw it as *brush over*.

Comment: To "brush up on" information is to re-learn it, as you say. But to "brush up" something -- without the "on" is to clean it up. If someone said, "I am going to brush up on the fuel injector section of the manual", I would take that to mean that he is going to re-read it and get it all back in his mind. But if he said, "I am going to brush up the fuel injector section of the manual", I would understand that to mean that he is involved in writing the manual and he is going to make some updates, fix errors, etc.